# json in xCode5 does not encode

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://192.168.178.1/iBus/appService/_getMarker.php"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *responseCode = nil;
    NSData *dataConnect;
    dataConnect = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];//connect todata
    NSDictionary * jsonObj;
    if (responseCode) {//if connect(response)

        NSLog(@"%@",dataConnect);//here is return data
        NSLog(@"%@",[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataConnect options:kNilOptions error:nil]);//here is return NULL!!!
    }
```

Its return NSData but not encode to JSON

Here is slog console
2014-12-18 13:14:00.997 iBus[2689:58536] (null)

Here is my json output : http://notes.io/Zd3

Comment: Are you getting data in dataConnect ?

Comment: You should use the error parameter in the JSONObjectWithData:options:error: method, and see what it returns.

Comment: have you checked it in browser ? its even not giving response on browser i checked. See this: http://192.168.178.1/iBus/appService/_getMarker.php

Comment: IS RETURN :  Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7f7fa3d3cc70 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

Comment: Your JSON response is invalid. It needs to be validated from server.

Comment: @cyberlobe Im checked its work!

Comment: check your JSON is valid or not. If it's invalid, then it'll be nil. Check the URL in browser and validate the JSON using any JSON formatter like jsonlint.org.

Comment: herer is simple json from url :[{"id":"BS000001","title":"\u0e1a\u0e32\u0e07\u0e0b\u0e37\u0e48\u0e2d","lat":"13.803173695997863","lng":"100.53933262825012"},{"id":"BS000002","title":"\u0e01\u0e33\u0e41\u0e1e\u0e07\u0e40\u0e1e\u0e0a\u0e23","lat":"13.79782087398948","lng":"100.54759919643402"},{"id":"BS000003","title":"\u0e08\u0e15\u0e38\u0e08\u0e31\u0e01\u0e23","lat":"13.803887396317272","lng":"100.5540418624878"}]

Comment: And that's not a valid JSON, copy and paste it in http://jsonlint.com/ and click on validate button. You can see the errors.

Comment: @Kampai i'm checked its work!!

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/JSONObjectWithData:options:error:), if JSONObjectWithData returns nil, that means an error occurs. You can read the error message by passing a reference to an `NSError` object to the `error:` argument.

As Kampai mentioned, this is likely caused by invalid JSON.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x7fb8f344e4c0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: @SupasitSuebsunthorn There you go, that's your error. You need to fix that.

Comment: I'm set options to NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
then error is return this

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.) UserInfo=0x7fa162f33ea0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Comment: @SupasitSuebsunthorn I think your JSON format is invalid.

Comment: @SupasitSuebsunthorn Can you try adding the JSON output to your question?